# MySQL While Loop Not Performing Insert Clause Every Time

Tags: php, mysql, insert, mysqli

There's a simple issue I'm having right now with a MySQL function. I am trying to run through a MySQL table and move data from that table to another. The one table is 'users' and the column 'user_id'. I'm trying to run a while loop to loop through all the rows in table users and create new rows in table 'new_users'. Here's my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$sql_create_new = "INSERT INTO new_users (user_id) VALUES ('$row[user_id]')";
$result_create_new = $mysqli->query($sql_create_new);
echo $row['user_id']."<br />";
}
```

It echoes out all the values of user_id in table users correctly so I know the loop is running. When I check the table new_users though, it only has one row (the first row) and doesn't actually add the other values. I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Probably some unique constrain fails. Show the table structure for new_users

Comment: What's wrong with `INSERT INTO new_users (user_id) (SELECT user_id FROM users)`? Also you're using `MySQLi` the not-so-properly way; suggest to prepare `INSERT INTO...VALUES (?)` and query this same statement inside loop instead of proposing a new query over and over again.

Comment: You should be building the query string in the loop and executing just one query

Comment: Please check your table structure. If you have unique constrain for that column and trying to insert duplicate records then it will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was mentioned in the comments as well, but it can't be stressed how important simplicity is:

```
$mysqli->query('INSERT INTO new_users (user_id) SELECT user_id FROM users');
```

To prevent conflicts with any records that are already in the destination table, use `INSERT IGNORE INTO` or `REPLACE INTO`.

Otherwise, you should use prepared statements properly:

```
$create_new_stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO new_users (user_id) VALUES (?)');

while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $create_new_stmt->bind_param('i', $row['user_id']);
    $create_new_stmt->execute();
    echo $row['user_id']."<br />";
}
```

Comment: You should check the value of your stmt variable isn't false for debugging reasons. You can't prepare multiple prepares on the same connection without closing, for instance.

Comment: @Hir Right, I guess, with PDO I depend on the exception error mode :)